# Find the interior points of the following set:

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I can identify each element of the set $\mathbb{Q}$ $\cap$ $[0,1[$; however, I must confess that it is pretty hard for me to use the proper open ball for it. I would really appreciate your help. Have a nice day and blessings. :)

Comment: There are no interior points because the set does not contain any open balls.

Comment: But... how can you assure that? I mean, it is easy to see that the intersection of those sets gives a set which contains elements of the rational numbers between 0 and 1. For example, I can see that 0 cannot be an element of the set of the interior points... but I still cannot realize the reason of your conclusion.

Comment: Let $q$ be any rational number. Then we can find irrational numbers arbitrarily close to $q$. For example, $q + \sqrt{2}/n$ is irrational for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: The point is that for any rational number $x$ and any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists an irrational number $y$ with $|x-y|<\epsilon$. One way to see this is to pick a positive irrational number $z$ and then consider $y=x+z/N$, where $N>z/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb Q\cap [0,1)$. Suppose there exists $r>0$ with $B_r(x)\subseteq\mathbb Q\cap [0,1)$. Then $y=x+r/2\in B_r(x)$. If $y$ is irrational, this is a contradiction. If $y$ is rational, there exists an irrational $z$ such that $x<z<y$ and $z\in B_r(x)$. This is also a contradiction, so $r=0$ is the only number such that $B_r(x)\subseteq\mathbb Q\cap[0,1).$ But in this case, $B_r(x)=\emptyset$. Since the interior of a set is the union of all balls which are subsets, the interior is also empty.